# Keep highlighted table row after pages refresh/login/logout - Javascript - Laravel - Mysql Option?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel and adding the highlighting option using javascript.  The highlighting works but after I refresh the page, logout and log back in the highlighted fields clear out.  Is there a way to keep/store the highlighted rows?  Thank you for the help in advanced!!

Is javascript the best option for this?  Is it possible to create a dropdown menu with the color options within my form, which will still highlight the row and store to the mysql database?

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myJSFunction(element) {
        var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;

        switch (element.options[element.selectedIndex].innerHTML) {
            case "Temporary":
                row.style.background = " #99c2ff";
                break;
            case "Special":
                row.style.background = " #ffff99";
                break;
            case "VIP":
                row.style.background = "#39ac39";
                break;
            case "Disapproved":
                row.style.background = " #ff3333";
                break;
            default:
                row.style.background = "white";
        }
    }
</script>
@section('content')
<h1>Office Assignments</h1>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Building</th>
            <th>Room</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Institution</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Semester</th>
            <th>Arrival</th>
            <th>Departure</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <th>NetId</th>
            <th>UniversityId</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Select Color</th>
            <th>Edit</th>


        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

        @foreach($offices as $office)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$office->building}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->room}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->type}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->institution}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->status}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->semester}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->arrival}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->departure}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->telephone}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->netId}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->universityId}}</td>
                <td>{{$office->notes}}</td>
                <td><select onchange="myJSFunction(this)">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>Special</option>
                        <option>VIP</option>
                        <option>Disapproved</option>
                        <option>Temporary</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td>
                    {{--Need the button to open up my edit form--}}
                    {{--<button href="lawoffices/{id}/edit">{{ trans('lawoffices.edit') }}</button>--}}
                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'Get', 'route' => ['lawoffices.edit', $office->id]]) !!}

                    {!! Form::submit('Edit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                    {{--<input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">--}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{--<div class="center">--}}
    {{--<div class="pagination"> {{$inventories->links()}}</div>--}}
    {{--</div>--}}
</div>
```

Comment: When you refresh the page (Sign Out ,Sign in) call your JavaScript function again and assign a highlight to the rows the way you said it works now.

Comment: If you use JavaScript you can use local storage to save data which will be later used to determine which rows should be highlighted.

Comment: @Matt.kaaj I am nnot quite sure I follow.